# Converting resources file to resx - not serializable

Tags: c#, resx, invalidoperationexception, reflector, resgen

I have a task where I'm reconstructing some source we lost for many projects. For the most, it's gone just fine, but of course on the very last project, I ran into an error that I cannot find any solution to.

I used Reflector 8.1 to decompile the DLL which gives me all the source and bunch of .resources files. I've been using the resgen program to convert them back into .resx files for inclusion in the project. One file is giving me grief though. Please help.

```
>resgen foo.resources foo.resx
Read in 106 resources from "foo.resources"
ResGen : error RG0000: Error while writing the output file "Resources.resx"
ResGen : error RG0000: Specific exception: "InvalidOperationException"  Message: "Item        named 'IncomingRing' of type 'System.IO.PinnedBufferMemoryStream' cannot
be added to the resource file because it is not serializable."
```

2 error(s).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

1. open the dll in Reflector
2. find the resource you are having problems with in the Resources folder of that assembly
3. right-click on it -> Open with -> Visual Studio 2010 or 2012

That should open it as a resx in visual studio